# Resolving 3rd party types in generated .d.ts files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Hi there I have a question. We are writing a component library that extends a 3rd party library. All the components work great in the package, but the types are all messed up. The generated .d.ts files look something like this for a button

```
/// <reference types="react" />
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button';
import './style/button.less';
interface CompoundedComponent extends React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<ButtonProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement>> {
    Group: typeof AntButton.Group;
}
declare const Button: CompoundedComponent;
export default Button;
```

Is there any way for the ts compiler to bring in those types instead of just referencing the import? We dont want to have to include ant in our parent projects and we also dont want to re-write all the types by hand.

Using rollup to build out the component library -- all the javascript is being included properly and the styles are being generated properly. its just the types that are off

Comment: I'm confused by what's "messed up" about the types.  Is this just an example?  I've used the `antd` package a lot and the types are correct -- the `CompoundedComponent` stuff is how they define `Button.Group` as a component which is also a property of the `Button` component.

Comment: These type files dont work when imported if the other project doesnt have ant installed because those imports dont resolve to anything